# on unimodality for Exponential Levy process

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

let $X_t$ be a levy process. I wonder is there any conditions for $Y_t=exp(X_t)$ to be unimodal? Are the conditions for $X_t$ to be unimodal still work for $Y_t$?